# how to shield a cpu from the linux scheduler (prevent it scheduling threads onto that cpu)?

Tags: linux, performance, real-time, scheduling

It is possible to use `sched_setaffinity` to pin a thread to a cpu, increasing performance (in some situations)

From the linux man page:

> Restricting a process to run on a single CPU also avoids the
>   performance cost caused by the cache invalidation that occurs when a
>   process ceases to execute on one CPU and then recommences execution on
>   a different CPU

Further, if I desire a more real-time response, I can change the scheduler policy for that thread to `SCHED_FIFO`, and up the priority to some high value (up to `sched_get_priority_max`), meaning the thread in question should always pre-empt any other thread running on its cpu when it becomes ready.

However, at this point, the thread running on the cpu which the real-time thread just pre-empted will possibly have evicted much of the real-time thread's level-1 cache entries.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to prevent the scheduler from scheduling any threads onto a given cpu? (eg: either hide the cpu completely from the scheduler, or some other way)
2. Are there some threads which absolutely have to be able to run on that cpu? (eg: kernel threads / interrupt threads)
3. If I need to have kernel threads running on that cpu, what is a reasonable maximum priority value to use such that I don't starve out the kernel threads?

Comment: Hello, I'm also facing the same question. Have you found out anything new on this?

Comment: @HongZhou - I found the cpuset utility which does exactly what I want - check out my added answer

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The answer is to use [cpusets](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/cpuset.7.html). The [python cpuset utility](http://code.google.com/p/cpuset/) makes it easy to configure them.

**Basic concepts**

*3 cpusets*

- `root`: present in all configurations and contains all cpus (*unshielded*)
- `system`: contains cpus used for system tasks - the ones which need to run but aren't "important" (*unshielded*)
- `user`: contains cpus used for "important" tasks - the ones we want to run in "realtime" mode (*shielded*)

The `shield` command manages these 3 cpusets.

During setup it moves all movable tasks into the unshielded cpuset (`system`) and during teardown it moves all movable tasks into the `root` cpuset.
After setup, the subcommand lets you move tasks into the *shield* (`user`) cpuset, and additionally, to move special tasks (kernel threads) from `root` to `system` (and therefore out of the `user` cpuset).

**Commands:**

First we create a shield. Naturally the layout of the shield will be machine/task dependent. For example, say we have a 4-core non-NUMA machine: we want to dedicate **3 cores to the shield**, and leave **1 core for unimportant tasks**; since it is non-NUMA we don't need to specify any memory node parameters, and we leave the kernel threads running in the `root` cpuset (ie: across all cpus)

```
$ cset shield --cpu 1-3
```

Some kernel threads (those which aren't bound to specific cpus) can be moved into the `system` cpuset. (In general it is not a good idea to move kernel threads which have been bound to a specific cpu)

```
$ cset shield --kthread on
```

Now let's list what's running in the shield (`user`) or unshielded (`system`) cpusets: (`-v` for verbose, which will list the process names) (add a 2nd `-v` to display more than 80 characters)

```
$ cset shield --shield -v
$ cset shield --unshield -v -v
```

If we want to stop the shield (teardown)

```
$ cset shield --reset
```

Now let's execute a process in the shield (commands following `'--'` are passed to the command to be executed, not to `cset`)

```
$ cset shield --exec mycommand -- -arg1 -arg2
```

If we already have a running process which we want to move into the shield (note we can move multiple processes by passing a comma separated list, or ranges (any process in the range will be moved, even if there are gaps))

```
$ cset shield --shield --pid 1234
$ cset shield --shield --pid 1234,1236
$ cset shield --shield --pid 1234,1237,1238-1240
```

**Advanced concepts**

`cset set/proc` - these give you finer control of cpusets

**Set**

Create, adjust, rename, move and destroy cpusets

*Commands*

Create a cpuset, using cpus 1-3, use NUMA node 1 and call it "my_cpuset1"

```
$ cset set --cpu=1-3 --mem=1 --set=my_cpuset1
```

Change "my_cpuset1" to only use cpus 1 and 3

```
$ cset set --cpu=1,3 --mem=1 --set=my_cpuset1
```

Destroy a cpuset

```
$ cset set --destroy --set=my_cpuset1
```

Rename an existing cpuset

```
$ cset set --set=my_cpuset1 --newname=your_cpuset1
```

Create a hierarchical cpuset

```
$ cset set --cpu=3 --mem=1 --set=my_cpuset1/my_subset1
```

List existing cpusets (depth of level 1)

```
$ cset set --list
```

List existing cpuset and its children

```
$ cset set --list --set=my_cpuset1
```

List all existing cpusets

```
$ cset set --list --recurse
```

**Proc**

Manage threads and processes

*Commands*

List tasks running in a cpuset

```
$ cset proc --list --set=my_cpuset1 --verbose
```

Execute a task in a cpuset

```
$ cset proc --set=my_cpuset1 --exec myApp -- --arg1 --arg2
```

Moving a task

```
$ cset proc --toset=my_cpuset1 --move --pid 1234
$ cset proc --toset=my_cpuset1 --move --pid 1234,1236
$ cset proc --toset=my_cpuset1 --move --pid 1238-1340
```

Moving a task and all its siblings

```
$ cset proc --move --toset=my_cpuset1 --pid 1234 --threads
```

Move all tasks from one cpuset to another

```
$ cset proc --move --fromset=my_cpuset1 --toset=system
```

Move unpinned kernel threads into a cpuset

```
$ cset proc --kthread --fromset=root --toset=system
```

Forcibly move kernel threads (including those that are pinned to a specific cpu) into a cpuset (note: this may have dire consequences for the system - make sure you know what you're doing)

```
$ cset proc --kthread --fromset=root --toset=system --force
```

**Hierarchy example**

We can use hierarchical cpusets to create prioritised groupings

1. Create a `system` cpuset with 1 cpu (0)
2. Create a `prio_low` cpuset with 1 cpu (1)
3. Create a `prio_met` cpuset with 2 cpus (1-2)
4. Create a `prio_high` cpuset with 3 cpus (1-3)
5. Create a `prio_all` cpuset with all 4 cpus (0-3) (note this the same as root;  it is considered good practice to keep a separation from root)

To achieve the above you create prio_all, and then create subset prio_high under prio_all, etc

```
$ cset set --cpu=0 --set=system
$ cset set --cpu=0-3 --set=prio_all
$ cset set --cpu=1-3 --set=/prio_all/prio_high
$ cset set --cpu=1-2 --set=/prio_all/prio_high/prio_med
$ cset set --cpu=1 --set=/prio_all/prio_high/prio_med/prio_low
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two other ways I can think of doing this (though not as elegant as cset, which doesn't seem to have a fantastic level of support from Redhat):

1) Taskset everything including PID 1 - nice and easy (but, alledgly  -- I've never seen any issues myself -- may cause inefficiencies in the scheduler).  The script below (which must be run as root) runs taskset on all the running processes, including init (pid 1); this will pin all the running processes to one or more 'junk cores', and by also pinning init, it will ensure that any future processes are also started in the list of 'junk cores':

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
  printf "Usage: %s '<csv list of cores to set as junk in double quotes>'", $0
  exit -1;
fi

for i in `ps -eLfad |awk '{ print $4 } '|grep -v PID | xargs echo `; do 
   taskset -pc $1 $i;
done
```

2) use the isolcpus kernel parameter (here's the documentation from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
isolcpus=   [KNL,SMP] Isolate CPUs from the general scheduler.
            Format:
            <cpu number>,...,<cpu number>
            or
            <cpu number>-<cpu number>
            (must be a positive range in ascending order)
            or a mixture
            <cpu number>,...,<cpu number>-<cpu number>

        This option can be used to specify one or more CPUs
        to isolate from the general SMP balancing and scheduling
        algorithms. You can move a process onto or off an
        "isolated" CPU via the CPU affinity syscalls or cpuset.
        <cpu number> begins at 0 and the maximum value is
        "number of CPUs in system - 1".

        This option is the preferred way to isolate CPUs. The
        alternative -- manually setting the CPU mask of all
        tasks in the system -- can cause problems and
        suboptimal load balancer performance.
```

I've used these two plus the cset mechanisms for several projects (incidentally, please pardon the blatant self promotion :-)),  I've just filed a patent for a tool called [Pontus Vision ThreadManager](http://www.pontusvision.com/case-studies/reduce-latency-by-20-x/)  that comes up with optimal pinning strategies for any given x86 platform to any given software work loads; after testing it in a customer site, I got really good results (270% reduction in peak latencies), so it's well worth doing pinning and CPU isolation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using rhel instance you can use Tuna for this (May be available for other linux distros also, but not sure about that). It can easily installed from yum command. Tuna can be used to isolate a cpu core and it dynamically moves processes run in that particular cpu to neighboring cpu. The command to isolate a cpu core is as follow,

`# tuna --cpus=CPU-LIST --isolate`

You can use `htop` to see how tuna isolate the cpu cores in real-time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it the old-fashioned way, using cgroups. I have a Fedora 28 machine and RedHat/Fedora want you to use `systemd-run`, but I wasn't able to find this functionality in there. I would love to know how to do it using `systemd-run`, if anyone would care to enlighten me.

Let's say I want to exclude my fourth CPU (of CPUs 0-3) from scheduling, and move all existing processes to CPUs 0-2. Then I want to put a process on CPU 3 all by itself.

```
sudo su -
cgcreate -g cpuset:not_cpu_3
echo 0-2 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/not_cpu_3/cpuset.cpus
# This "0" is the memory node. See https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/NUMAMemoryInfo
# for more information *
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/not_cpu_3/cpuset.mems
```

- Specifically, on your machine you'll want to review `/proc/zoneinfo` and the `/sys/devices/system/node` heirarchy. Getting the proper node information is left as an exercise for the reader.

Now that we have our cgroup, we need to create our isolated CPU 3 cgroup:

```
cgcreate -g cpuset:cpu_3
echo 3 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpu_3/cpuset.cpus
# Again, the memory node(s) you want to specify.
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpu_3/cpuset.mems
```

Put all processes/threads on the `not_cpu_3` cgroup:

```
for pid in $(ps -eLo pid) ; do cgclassify -g cpuset:not_cpu_3 $pid; done
```

Review:

```
ps -eL k psr o psr,pid,tid,args | sort | cut -c -80
```

NOTE! Processes currently in sleep *will not move*. They must be awakened so that the scheduler will put them on a different CPU. To see this, choose your favorite sleeping process in the above list- a process, say a web browser, that you thought should be on CPU 0-2 but it's still on 3. Using its thread ID from the above list, perform:

```
kill -CONT <thread_id>
```

example

```
kill -CONT 9812
```

Rerun the ps command, and note that it's moved to another CPU.

DOUBLE NOTE! Some kernel threads *cannot* and will not move! For example, you may note that every CPU has a kernel thread `[kthreadd]` on it. Assigning processes to cgroups works for userspace processes, not for kernel threads. This is life in the multitasking world.

Now to move a process and all its children to control group cpu_3:

```
pid=12566 # for example
cgclassify -g cpuset:cpu_3 $pid
taskset -c -p 3 $pid
```

Again, if `$pid` is sleeping, you'll need to wake it up for the CPU move to actually take place.

To undo all of this, simply delete the cgroups you've created. Everybody will be stuck back into the root cgroup:

```
cgdelete -r cpuset:cpu_3
cgdelete -r cpuset:not_cpu_3
```

No need to reboot.

(Sorry, I don't understand the 3rd question from the original poster. I can't comment on that.)