# Allocate a full CPU to a specific thread in order to maximize performance and avoid context switch

Tags: multithreading, scheduled-tasks, cpu-usage, multitasking, affinity

I have a task **not parallelizable** that I want to process as fast as possible.
This task performs pure computation, no I/O.

Of course this task runs on a multi-core system and many other processes are simultaneously doing "things" that also also require CPU usage.

Today, my task is optimized as far as possible (let's say it's perfect :-P), my idea to boost it once again would be to allocate a full CPU for its thread.

In these conditions, no other threads would share the CPU with it, and so, no context switch would interrupt my task; doing that should to speed it a little bit once again with almost no effort.
(of course, this would be done to the detriment of other processes but this is not a problem at all: the highest priority is given to **my** task!)

But how can I do what I want? I know how to set the affinity of the thread of my task in order to assign it to a given CPU but this CPU will potentially be shared with other threads; my problem is not solved

Thank you for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to shield a cpu from the linux scheduler (prevent it scheduling threads onto that cpu)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111852/how-to-shield-a-cpu-from-the-linux-scheduler-prevent-it-scheduling-threads-onto)

Answer (score 0):

While investigating this question, I finally found the following interesting links:

- [man cpuset](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/fr/man7/cpuset.7.html) (in french)
- [Kernel Parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)
- [Assign an individual core to a process](https://superuser.com/questions/1082194/assign-an-individual-core-to-a-process)
- [Cpuset Management Utility/tutorial](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_Management_Utility/tutorial#Listing_Cpusets_with_Set)
- [One core exclusively for my process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072060/one-core-exclusively-for-my-process)